# Can you pay with Litecoin anywhere you can pay with Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, litecoin, spending

Can you pay with Litecoin at any place that accepts Bitcoin? If no where can you spend Litecoins?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged transactions litecoin spending or ask your own question.

Answer (score 9):

Merchants that only accept Bitcoin, will not accept Litecoin directly.

However you can pay any Bitcoin merchant with a 3rd party that automatically converts your Litecoin to Bitcoin. The most well known service of this type is shapeshift.io

Merchants can integrate their "shifty" button to make this easier for consumers to use, but the Shapeshift service is available for every consumer wishing to pay a Bitcoin merchant regardless of if they have integrating the Shapeshift API or not.

https://shapeshift.io/shifty_button.html

https://shapeshift.io/#/coins

Answer (score 6):

While the process of spending Litecoins is extremely similar to Bitcoins, it is an alternative currency without a community accepted fixed exchange to Bitcoin therefore the merchant has to accept the work of conversion.

To the best of my understanding, Bitpay, bitmit.net and the other major markets and payment portals do not accept Litecoin. I'll refer you to this discussion as it probably is more informed and active than anything you'll get in a stackexchange format https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=139940.0

Comment: I'll see if I can fish some more links out for you

Answer (score 2):

ltc and btc are two different crypto currencies and are treated as such.  For example, BitInstant currently does NO business in ltc.  However, you will find some places like btc-e will deal in BOTH ltc AND btc.